# How to show ignorated attributes in Weka

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, arff

I have .arff file:

```
@RELATION Employee
@ATTRIBUTE EmployeeID string
@ATTRIBUTE sex {male,female}
@ATTRIBUTE age {young,middle-age,old-age}

@DATA
’5s6s6ss’,male,old-age
’5s6s6tt’,female,old-age
’5s6s6ii’,male,young
```

i want to make cluster in WEKA, but i have string attribute "EmployeeID". I have to ignore string attribute, but how to show which EmployeeID is in cluster 0 and cluster 1?

Answer (score 0):

In the "Preprocess" panel use the unsupervised attribute Filter `AddCluster`  to add the Cluster Assigmment to the Result. Do not forget to set the `ignoreAttributeIndices` value in the configuration dialog-box of the filter. Here you should enter "1" in order to exclude the EmployeeID from the clustering process (because it has too much predictive/discriminative power). The attribute value will still be displayed in the table.